# Why fgets just have one line when i want to count the number of char

Tags: c, string, char, fgets

I tried this to count the number of char in a .txt that looks like that

```
ID2;Orelsan;San;Musiques\\Orelsan San.mp3
ID1;Rick Astley;Never Gonna Give You Up;Musiques\\Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up.mp3
```

I wrote this but the `stringsize` is equal to the number of char in line 2

```
int search(){

FILE *inputFile;
char buffer[255];
int sizestring=0;

inputFile=fopen("bddmp3.txt","rt");

fgets(buffer2,255,inputFile);
while(inputFile!=EOF){
    sizestring++;
}
printf("%d",sizestring);
```

I tried another way using `strlen`, but i have the same problem, i just have the length of the first line

```
FILE *inputFile;
char buffer[255];
int toto;
int stringsize=0;

inputFile=fopen("bddmp3.txt","r");

stringsize= strlen(fgets(buffer,255,inputFile));
printf("taille :%d\n",stringsize);
```

Comment: You're comparing a `FILE*` with a plain `int` value, C just doesn't work that way. Instead check what [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) *return*.

Comment: The computer is doing what you told it to do.

Comment: `stringsize= strlen(fgets(buffer,255,inputFile));` is a terrible idea. `fgets` will return `NULL` once you try to end beyond the end of the file. And `strlen(NULL)` is not going to end well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgets` returns `NULL` (and not `EOF`) if there is no more data left to read.

You probably want this:

```
inputFile = fopen("bddmp3.txt", "rt");
if (inputFile == NULL) {
  .. handle error
}

while (fgets(buffer2,255,inputFile) != NULL) {
    sizestring++;
}
```

This doesn't make sense:

```
while(inputFile!=EOF){
    sizestring++;
}
```

1. you compare `inputFile` which is a `FILE*` to an `int` which doesn't make any sense
2. `sizestring++` cannot possibly change `inputFile`, therefore this loop will most likely run for ever.

Comment: it doesnt work, i tried another way : ```taillestring = strlen(fgets(buffer,255,inputFile))``` but doesnt work too, strlen just gave me the size of the first line

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72288748/edit) and add your new code as [mcve] or possibly ask a new question. But don't remove your buggy code from the question, otherwise it would invalidate all commenst and answers.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion: Programs like this are better written in terms of fgetc(), which reads single characters. You can then examine each character and easily count lines (by counting '\n' i.e. newlines) or the total number of characters. With this approach, you do not need to allocate a buffer for each line (your current problem would have a bug: what happens if the line is over 255 characters?), and it can easily handle files with lines of any length.
Reading character-by-character with fgetc() is not inefficient, because of the buffering implemented in the stdio library.